# I want to only read specific line from my text file with PHP

Tags: php, file

I have a text file with contains data like ;

```
something1
something2
something3
something4
```

I need to get the data of the fourth line and echo it in php.

I have tried code from the net but it does not work.
Thank you.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
echo file("txtfile")['3'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, it reads the file line by line and breaks on third line.

```
<?php
    $file = fopen("test.txt","r");

    $i =0;
    while(! feof($file))

    {
     if($i==3){
      echo fgets($file). "<br />";
      break;
     }
     $i++;  
    }

    fclose($file);
?>
```